# how to sync server's time and date from sever to client without internet

Tags: vb6

I am working on a project (using visual basic 6) that will get the server's date-time and change the clients' date-time. The problem is the computers don't have internet access.

The computers run windows vista and Sqlite R2.. Is it possible to write a code to do that and how may i achieve it?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: I would use any NTP server and clients - but there's nothing to do with VB. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7dc5e8f4-824a-432c-a2da-ac0e3fdf76fd/configuring-ntp-server?forum=winserverNIS

Comment: So the computers are in a local network? They have connection to each other, right?

Comment: yes! they are connected with "Desktop Switch".

Comment: Dont I need an internet connection for NTP or SNTP server?

Comment: You don't need the Internet.  You just need at least one machine on the same network running the NTP server.  Then all other machines use that server as their NTP server and they will all sync their time to that one server.  Now you just need to figure out how to keep that one server's time correct.

Comment: I answered with the windowsw ntp client command but some idiot call ed **Yuval Itzchakov** couldn't understand it. Look at the w32tm /resync command. w32tm /? for help.
And remember your computer does this automatically every so many minutes.